# Firebase Can Read, But I'm Not Able To Post

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

App I've created is able to read data from firebase no problem. However, when I try to write data to it, doesn't seem to be working. I checked my rules to make sure ".write" was set to true, still not seeing anything pop up.

Trying to write an event to firebase as follows: `ref?.child(email).child("events").setValue("Test")`

Email variable has a value, though to double check it wasn't something weird with it I even tried substituting email for "test". Have no idea where else I could be going wrong, any help is a godsend!

Full code for reference:

```
//
//  NewEventToCreateVC.swift
//  WSUStudentEvents
//
//  Created by Colin Warn on 7/31/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Colin Warn. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase

class NewEventToCreateVC: UIViewController {
    var eventToCreate: UserEvent?



    @IBOutlet weak var titleOutlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startTimeOutlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var endTimeOutlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventTypeOutlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationOutlet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionOutlet: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordOutlet: UILabel!

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    var ref: DatabaseReference?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = DatabaseReference().database.reference()

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        var startDateString = ""
        var endDateString = ""
        if let startTime = eventToCreate?.startTime, let endTime = eventToCreate?.endTime {
            startDateString = formatter.string(from: startTime)
            endDateString = formatter.string(from: endTime)
        }


        titleOutlet.text = eventToCreate?.eventName
        startTimeOutlet.text = startDateString
        endTimeOutlet.text = endDateString
        eventTypeOutlet.text = eventToCreate?.eventType
        locationOutlet.text = eventToCreate?.eventLocation
        descriptionOutlet.text = eventToCreate?.description
        if let password = eventToCreate?.password {
            if password == "" {
                passwordOutlet.text = "(no password)"
            } else {
                passwordOutlet.text = "Password: \(password)"
            }

        }


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("EVENT TO CREATE, new VC data transfer check")
        print(eventToCreate)
        print(eventToCreate?.eventName)
    }


    @IBAction func addEventPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        uploadDataToFirebase()
    }



    @IBAction func backBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddEventViewModelVC") as! AddEventViewModelVC
        if let eventName = eventToCreate?.eventName {
            nextViewController.eventName = eventName
        }

        if let eventLocation = eventToCreate?.eventLocation {
            nextViewController.eventLocation = eventLocation
        }

        nextViewController.startTime = eventToCreate?.startTime
        nextViewController.endTime = eventToCreate?.endTime
        if let description = eventToCreate?.description {
            nextViewController.eventDescription = description
        }

        if let password = eventToCreate?.password {
            nextViewController.password = password

        }

        if let eventType = eventToCreate?.eventType
        {
            nextViewController.eventType = eventType
        }
        nextViewController.eventEnum = .password



        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion: {
            nextViewController.titleLabel.text = nextViewController.eventEnum.rawValue
            nextViewController.textField.text = self.eventToCreate?.password
        })
    }

    func uploadDataToFirebase(){


        let email = defaults.object(forKey: "email") as! String
        print(email)

        //Email->Events->Data

        //Set Email


        //Set events
        ref?.child(email).child("events").setValue("Test")



    }

}
```

Thank you so much in advance:

Comment: I assume `let email = defaults.object(forKey: "email") as! String` is an email? Because keys in the Firebase Database cannot have periods in them, so that might explain the problem.

Comment: Way to much code and opportunities for errors - what if let email was nil or "" or had an invalid char like a period in it? Try to create a [Minimal Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needed to duplicate the issue.

Comment: @Jay tred creating a minimal example: ref?.child("Lincolnasasa").setValue("Bill")

Still nothing appearing in Firebase, even after refreshing.

Comment: DatabaseReference().database.reference() is the issue - see my answer.

Comment: @JenPerson ahhh good to know.  Definitely a problem I would've run into, however still having issues uploading even just a minimal example.  Thanks for that heads up though.

Comment: @jay pardon the extremely dumb question:  What would the problem with my DatabaseReference().database.reference() line be?  I have it written exactly like you state, and it's in viewDidLoad().  Also have changed the initialization of it to a "!" instead of a "?", and it still didn't work.

Comment: Look carefully: *DatabaseReference().database.reference()* is not the same as *Database.database().reference()*

Comment: @jay I'm an idiot.  Thank you so much.

Comment: My pleasure and no you're not - it's a super easy mistake to make!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking things down to minimal code can often help in troubleshooting. For example, try this

```
@class xxxx
  var ref: DatabaseReference!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       ref = Database.database().reference()
       ref.child("events").setValue("test")
  }
```

Which will result in a Firebase like this

```
root_ref
   events: "test"
```

It's also a good idea to include closures in your Firebase calls so you can catch any errors... so instead of setValue, you could use setValue with it's completion block (closure in swift)

```
let eventsRef = self.ref.child("events")
eventsRef.setValue("test", withCompletionBlock: { error in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    }
})
```

Comment: appreciate the help so far.  Tried your closure error test as using "ref?", got no error back.  However, I'm noticing when I use "ref" instead, I get the following error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"